# Vulnerability issue with Android app. X509 implementation

Tags: android, android-studio, x509trustmanager

Recently started receiving email notifications from Google regarding my Android app suggesting below
To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever the certificate presented by the server does not meet your expectations. You may refer to this Help Center article for additional guidance

The SSL socketfactory.javav file looks as below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class SimpleSSLSocketFactory extends org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();

    public SimpleSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(null);

        try {
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains and simply accept all type of certificates
            X509TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new X509TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }
            }};

            // Initialize the socket factory
            context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
            sslFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
            throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslFactory.createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslFactory.createSocket();
    }
}
```

I have read through various articles dated back to 2016 that suggest some measures but none of them seems to work here . Has someone been able to get through this? Email also sets a deadline to remove the app from the play store if the vulnerability is not fixed

Comment: Why do you have this insecure trust manager there to begin with? Remove it, and if it is there to solve an actual problem, find a secure way to solve it.

Comment: That's what i am looking for. A secure way to accept only my domain certificate

Comment: Look up "certificate pinning" then.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into it as haven't used it before. Do you have any running code for reference ? That would help me save time and efforts

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue , We are using thermostat which has html urls which we can not change, So we want to address this issue with some code change only. Answer on this post could help us also.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you have the same issue, you might want to create a new question by clicking on [ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and make a reference to this question.